# How to Detect Screen Height for Responsive Design

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I am working on building a site for responsive design.

I have a certain CSS style as follows:

```
/* when viewport height less than 320px */
@media screen and (max-height: 319px) { /* TRIED FOR IPHONE -- CAN'T GET TO WORK YET */

    #footer {
        font-size: 65%;
        line-height: 110%;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }

}
```

I tested it on my iPhone in landscape mode and the font-size does not change to 65%, nor do any of these 3 styles take effect. Is this a valid and proper way to detect the screen height dimension for an iPhone?

Comment: Are you placing this code before or after your regular CSS?

Comment: Yes, in the cascade, this is the very last style block I have. Right above it I have a style for max-width for iPhone portrait and it works fine.

Comment: if it makes a difference I have an iPhone 4

Comment: can you post the entire code on a jsfiddle or better yet, give the website link? You are probably missing a bracket.

Comment: I'm getting a login panel. Do you mean the homepage? You linked to homepage/OMS

Comment: That's correct @JohnSmith. You should be at the login panel. When I view the login panel on my iPhone 4 in portrait mode the footer text reduces to 65%. When I rotate the iPhone 4 to landscape, the text does not reduce to 65%. It is the footer that I am trying to get to appear in the viewport (as well as teach myself responsive design). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try using a different media query?

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```
@media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
}
```

I have never had a problem with media queries. After testing your website through an online iPhone emulator in both portrait and landscape mode, the font-size is set to 65%:

http://www.testiphone.com/

However, if the media query above does not work, could you try changing your viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Comment: What is interesting about the link you sent me to @JohnSmith is none of them use the max-height attribute. They do use orientation:landscape. Maybe I should try that.

Comment: if it's a portrait/landscape issue, you may want to change your viewport http://chriscoyier.net/2009/01/25/iphone-meta-tag-for-viewport-maintaining-scale-on-orientation-change/. Overall if none of this works, I'm stumped.

Comment: Every "trick" I try that you suggested or sent a link for, works on my browser. When I go to the actual iPhone it does not work. I'm stumped too, but thanks for helping @JohnSmith!

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($(document).width() <= 320){
      $("#footer").addClass("newclass")
   }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.newclass {
    font-size: 65%;
    line-height: 110%;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: So @Enve, are you stating that I cannot use `@media screen and (max-height: 319px) {}` in my CSS?

Comment: It is CSS3 and not supported on all browsers

Comment: who uses IE7 and IE8 on an iphone?

Comment: What about the iPhone4 in Safari? That is what the style is directed at.

Comment: I think jQuery is the best way. You also have aded jquery to your site

Comment: I use jQuery for other functionality on the site @Enve. I am trying to learn responsive via CSS3. Do you feel that `@media screen and (max-height: 319px) {}` cannot be used?